# MCNearbyServiceBrowser randomly crashes on applicationWillResignActive (zombie)

Tags: ios, appdelegate, multipeer-connectivity, zombie-process

I am writing a Multipeer App and have a somewhat random crash whenever my app goes into the background. It may happen the first time or not until the 30th time, so I suspect it is a threading/timing issue, but am not sure how to solve it.

I get the "message sent to deallocated instance" for [MCNearbyServiceBrowser syncStopBrowsingForPeers] which is not a public method, but is likely called when I am calling stopBrowsingForPeers.

I am using setUp/Start and Stop/shutdown methods so I can start/stop and restart sessions among peers. Below is the relevant code.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong unless MultiPeer is doing something behind the scenes that I can't see that is causing the browser to deallocate.

```
@interface SSSSessionContainer : NSObject <MCSessionDelegate,
                                       MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate,
                                       MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate>
{
    // Our peer ID used to advertise ourselves and identify ourselves
    MCPeerID *_peerID ;

    // Our set of sessions. One per peer keyed off of peer display name
    NSMutableDictionary *_sessionList ;
    
    // Our service advertiser that announces us to peers
    MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *_serviceAdvertiser ;

    // Our browser that searches for nearby peers
    MCNearbyServiceBrowser *_serviceBrowser ;
}

// Called when we are starting our message services. Either when app first starts or comes back from background
- (void) setupSessionServices ;

// Called when we are about to shutdown (go to background)
- (void) shutdownSessionServices ;

// Called when we start services because user changed Buddy Finder settings to ON
- (void) startServices ;

// Called when we stop services because user changed Buddy Finder settings to OFF
- (void) stopServices ;
```

and the implementation

```
- (void) setupSessionServices
{
    // Create the service advertiser
    _serviceAdvertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID
                                                       discoveryInfo:nil
                                                         serviceType:kSSSServiceType];
    _serviceAdvertiser.delegate = self;

    // Create the service browser
    _serviceBrowser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID
                                                   serviceType:kSSSServiceType];

    _serviceBrowser.delegate = self;

    // should never happen, but make sure we start with no sessions
    [_sessionList removeAllObjects] ;
}

- (void)shutdownSessionServices
{
    // Nil out delegates
    if ( _serviceAdvertiser != nil )
    {
        _serviceAdvertiser.delegate = nil;
    }

    if ( _serviceBrowser != nil )
    {
        _serviceBrowser.delegate = nil;
    }

    // nil out the advertiser and browser
    _serviceAdvertiser = nil ;
    _serviceBrowser = nil ;
}

- (void)startServices
{
    if ( _serviceAdvertiser != nil )
    {
        [_serviceAdvertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
    }
    if ( _serviceBrowser != nil )
    {
        [_serviceBrowser startBrowsingForPeers];
    }
}

- (void)stopServices
{
    // Disconnect all of our current sessions
    NSArray *allSessions = [_sessionList allValues] ;

    for ( MCSession *session in allSessions )
    {
        [session disconnect];
    }

    // remove all session instances
    [_sessionList removeAllObjects] ;

    if ( _serviceAdvertiser != nil )
    {
        [_serviceAdvertiser stopAdvertisingPeer];
    }

    if ( _serviceBrowser != nil )
    {
        // This is the line that randomly crashes with zombie!
        [_serviceBrowser stopBrowsingForPeers]; 
    }
}
```

and in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Stop our services
    [[SSSSessionContainer sharedStore] stopServices] ;

    // Shut down our services
    [[SSSSessionContainer sharedStore] shutdownSessionServices] ;
}
```

And finally, here is the trace from instruments

> 0  Malloc    +1    1   00:36.794.439   MyApp                       -[SSSSessionContainer setupSessionServices]
>
> 1  Retain    +1    2   00:36.794.491   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib    _Block_copy_internal
>
> 2  Release   -1    1   00:36.796.463   libdispatch.dylib            _dispatch_client_callout
>
> 3  Retain    +1    2   00:40.572.193   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib   _Block_copy_internal
>
> 4  Release   -1    1   00:40.572.214   MyApp                       -[SSSAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:]
>
> 5  Release   -1    0   00:40.589.083   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout
>
> 6  Zombie     -1   0   0:40.590.426    MultipeerConnectivity   -[MCNearbyServiceBrowser syncStopBrowsingForPeers]

So, it appears the applicationWillResignActive is releasing it and then there is a call to stopBrowsingForPeers, but it seems like it is releasing it BEFORE I call shutdown. Help!

Here is the relevant portion of the crash log:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001036d1e34 _os_lock_corruption_abort + 0
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001036d1e34 _OSSpinLockLockSlow + 125
2   CFNetwork                           0x0000000102d77e86 CFNetServiceBrowserStopSearch + 60
3   MultipeerConnectivity               0x000000010016c947 -[MCNearbyServiceBrowser syncStopBrowsingForPeers] + 68
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102671d9c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025d451d _CFXNotificationPost + 2381
6   Foundation                          0x0000000101f3f7fa -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
7   UIKit                               0x0000000100f2e4bc -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 847
8   UIKit                               0x0000000100f38711 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1594
9   UIKit                               0x0000000100f39216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
10  UIKit                               0x0000000100f29086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
11  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010405671a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
12  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001040561e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010259e679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010259e44e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025c7903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025c6d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104054f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
18  UIKit                               0x0000000100f28e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
19  MyApp                               0x00000001000913b3 main + 115 (main.m:16)
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001036c85fd start + 1
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log?

Comment: Updated to add the crash log on the thread that crashed (main thread)